# ionic multiple view states for one tab

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a four tab setup and it works just as desired.

On one of the tabs however, I want there to be three states inside it. Reason being because I want the tab to stay active but while showing different content states. I made two extra states by adding "hidden" tabs but then the tab icon at the bottom isn't "active" anymore when using the additional states.

How can I make it so that I can have multiple states for one tab while keeping that tab's icon active the whole time? I should mention that I want to keep < back functionality as well.

## App.Config

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('welcome', {
    url:'/',
    templateUrl:'templates/welcome.html',
    controller:'WelcomeCtrl'
  })
  .state('sign-up', {
    url: '/sign-up',
    templateUrl: 'templates/sign-up.html',
    controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
  })
  .state('forgot-password', {
    url:'/forgot-password',
    templateUrl:'templates/forgot-password.html',
    controller:'ForgotPasswordCtrl'
  })

  .state('tabs', {
    url:'/tab',
    abstract:true,
    templateUrl:'templates/tabs.html'
  })
  .state('tabs.map', {
    url:'/map',
    views: {
      'map-tab':{
        templateUrl:'templates/map.html',
        controller:'MapCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tabs.favorites', {
    url:'/favorites',
    views: {
      'favorites-tab':{
        templateUrl:'templates/favorites.html',
        controller:'FavoritesCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tabs.coupons', {
    url:'/coupons',
    views: {
      'coupons-tab':{
        templateUrl:'templates/coupons.html',
        controller:'CouponsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('singles', {
    url:'/singles/{location_id:\\d+}',
    cache: false,
    templateUrl:'templates/singles.html',
    controller:'SinglesCtrl'
  })
  .state('coupon', {
    url:'/coupon/{location_id:\\d+}/{coupon_id:\\d+}',
    cache: false,
    templateUrl:'templates/coupon.html',
    controller:'CouponCtrl'
  })
  .state('tabs.settings', {
    url:'/settings',
    views: {
      'settings-tab':{
        templateUrl:'templates/settings.html',
        controller:'SettingsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})
```

## Tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs id="app-tabs" class="tabs-icon-top">

  <ion-tab title="Coupons" icon-on="coupon-active" icon-off="coupon-inactive" href="#/tab/coupons">
    <ion-nav-view name="coupons-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Map" icon-on="map-active" icon-off="map-inactive" href="#/tab/map">
    <ion-nav-view name="map-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Favorites" icon-on="favorite-active" icon-off="favorite-inactive" href="#/tab/favorites">
    <ion-nav-view name="favorites-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Settings" icon-on="settings-active" icon-off="settings-inactive" href="#/tab/settings">
    <ion-nav-view name="settings-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

When clicking on an item in "#/coupons" the url I'm trying to go to is "#/singles/" followed by "#/coupon//" and I want singles and coupon (singular) to be part of the "Coupons" tab.

Comment: Why not have all the three views, corresponding to the three states, in the same tab, and hidden/shown using ng-if .. Also, when you ask such contextual questions, posting a little code makes a little more sense

Comment: what do you mean by "using ng-if" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would be nice to see an example of what exactly you want but if I'm interpreting right you could have something like:

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

  <ion-tab title="Profile" icon-off="ion-person" icon-on="ion-person" href="#/app/profile/{{currentUser.id}}">
      <ion-nav-view name="feed"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Friends" icon-off="ion-person-stalker" icon-on="ion-person-stalker" href="#/app/friends">
       <ion-nav-view name="friends"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

app.js

```
.state('app', {
  url: "/app",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html",
  controller: 'AppCtrl'
})

.state('app.feed', {
  url: "/feed",
  views: {
    'feed' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/feed.html",
      controller: 'FeedCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('app.friends', {
      url: "/friends",
      views: {
        'friends' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/friends.html",
          controller: 'FriendsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
.state('app.add-friends', {
      url: "/add-friends",
      views: {
        'friends' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/add-friends.html",
          controller: 'AddFriendsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
.state('app.do-something', {
      url: "/do-something",
      views: {
        'friends' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/do-something.html",
          controller: 'DoSomethingCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

Note that there are three states for the friends tab, "app.friends", "app.add-friends", and "app.do-something". The key here is naming the views for each of these states 'friends', which corresponds to the tab's ion-nav-view name.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but when instead of going to the new tab while keeping the current tab highlighted it just went to the default state. I posted code in an edit which will hopefully help, sorry I didn't do that earlier.

Comment: After doing more research and after reading your paragraph below your code until it sank in I finally get the concept. It's silly how simple this is and that I still overthought it. Also, here a working example of this idea: http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/VLwLOG