# How do I add a new state to ui-router with Ionic tab

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am building an app using the Ionic framework tabbed view.  Ionic already gives me tabs at the bottom but I also want two buttons at the top that changes the view.  I cannot seem to get this to work.  Specifically the one at the top right (see screenshot).  Right now, when you click on it; it does nothing.

[image]
This is the tab interface they give me:

```
<ion-view id="page1">
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-stable tabs-icon-bottom" id="tabsController-tabs1">
    <ion-tab icon="ion-ios-photos" href="#/page1/index" id="tabsController-tab1">
      <ion-nav-view name="tab1"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab icon="ion-camera" ng-if="timer === '0m'" ng-click="indexController.camera()">
      <ion-nav-view name="tab3"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="{{timer}}" ng-if="timer !== '0m'" disabled="true" ng-if="true" ng-click="indexController.camera()">
      <ion-nav-view name="tab3"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab icon="ion-android-list" href="#/page1/bestMoments" id="tabsController-tab2">
      <ion-nav-view name="tab2"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-view>
```

In my routes.js I have this state for my new button:

```
  .state('tabsController.myMoments', {
    url: '/myMoments',
    cache:false,
    views: {
      'tab4': {
        templateUrl: 'myMoments/myMoments.html',
        controller: 'MyMomentsController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      }
    }
  })
```

I have also, sort of 'hacked' the button.  Its not actually a tabbed state, its just a button with a ng-click that sends you to the desired state.  I put this code in my index.html:

```
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <div class="ion-person" ng-click="indexController.redirectMyMoments()"></div>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
```

I don't understand where I am supposed to put 'tab4'.  My assumption is that it goes with these rest of my tabs but no matter where I put it, it seems to mess up my other tabs and I don't want to make another ion-tab in there because I don't want it to be at the bottom.

I have also noticed that if I change the view name to 'tab3' it actually works so it is changing the state correctly, however, it highlights the third tab when you click on the top right view which is also bad.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

Plunker of my problem:

https://plnkr.co/edit/PTS9Jt?p=preview

Comment: just use `ui-sref` instead of indexController.redirectMyMoments()

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: I have answered your question @MatTaNg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last tab name is suppose to be `tab4` instead of `tab2` in your tab interface.

```
<ion-view id="page1">
```

```
  <ion-tab icon="" href="#/page1/index" id="tabsController-tab2">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab2"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab icon="ion-camera" ng-if="timer === '0m'" ng-click="indexController.camera()">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab3"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab title="{{timer}}" ng-if="timer !== '0m'" disabled="true" ng-if="true" ng-click="indexController.camera()">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab3"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab icon="ion-android-list" href="#/page1/bestMoments" id="tabsController-tab4">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab4"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

Replace your code with this.

--------------------------UPDATE------------------------

Now, for Tab-3, You cannot have multiple tabs with same name. So what you can do in it is you can create a nested view in it. As in, you can have 2 views in it with different names.. one timer and one camera(OR ANYTHING ELSE YOU WANT). Here is the reference of multiple views in one tab.  [ionic multiple view states for one tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158202/ionic-multiple-view-states-for-one-tab)

Now each of your tab will have a unique name and a unique-associated `id` for them. So you can style it as you want it to look like.

Comment: Its just out of order; tab2 is the tab you are looking at in my screenshot.  I need tab2 but I don't know where to put tab4.

Comment: See the lasy tab you mentioned ... Just change its name to tab4 .. Tab2 is already declared 2nd from the top.. So it will remain working

Comment: I made the change but now when I click on the myMoments button(top right) it highlights tab 2 and displays the correct view.  I want it to take you to the correct view but not highlight anything on the bottom bar since it's its' own view.

Comment: If anything I'd want it to highlight the picture of the person on the top right

Comment: Alright .. I ll help you solve it for an upvote and mark as correct

Comment: I updated the answer again ..  Change the id of tab4 as i did in the code in my answer

Comment: Moreover there cannot be 2 tabs with same name .. You have got 2 `tab3`

Comment: I still want tab2.  #/page1/bestMoments IS tab2 so I still need tab2.  I'm trying to add another tab but on the top right, not on the bottom.  The reason why I have 2 tab3's is because I wanted a countdown timer for tab3 so I 'replaced' it with another tab without an icon.  When the countdown reaches 0, it will display the other tab3 with the icon.  Its a bit hacky but it seems to work but it does mess up the order of the tabs for some reason.

Comment: If you need timer in tab3 , add it in its html view.. Cuz this approach  will certainly mess it all up.. Or else creat a sub view for tab3

Comment: Oh.. Sorry.. Wait a min

Comment: I don't actually want another tab on the bottom.  I'd like my new view to be on the top right, not on the bottom.  With this change I have four buttons on the bottom (I did not delete tab1).  I basically want the button to be on the top right and when you click on it.  It highlights the top right button and not any of the 3 buttons on the bottom and its a completely separate view from any of the other ones.

Comment: Okay.. I got you .. I actually got a lecture now.. I ll get back to this in a couple of hours

Comment: Okay, I'm going to sleep its midnight now.  Thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: I can't mark your answer as correct if you didn't answer the question.

Comment: I meant I answered the problem that you mentioned in the question.. not the other problems that arose later on.. I would help for solving the other problems for a vote up and Mark as correct.. anyways.. all the best finding the answer ahead.

Comment: If you would like me to mark your question as correct before answering it that's fine, I would just like the question answered in return.  The way I see it, we had a miscommunication and the question wasn't answered because of that.  You went away for a while so I just thought you gave up or forgot.  I'll mark your answer as correct again if you'd like to answer if; if not I'll still keep the upvote for your efforts.

Comment: I've been trying to do that actually but with not much luck.  It's difficult to redo all these routes from scratch.  If I manage to do it I'll let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142449/discussion-between-tirthraj-barot-and-mattang).